# Prestashop webservice API for return orders

Tags: php, prestashop, webapi

I want to get all return orders in Prestashop through Prestashop webservice library, but I cannot find any API method or resource.
I have checked Prestashop documentation https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/resources/ and find in other sources or forums for help but did not find any solution.
Can anyone provide any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`return orders` is not added to the default Prestashop webservice.

You need to change the Prestashop code with a custom module and an override of the `OrderReturn.php` to make it work.